# jQuery UI : Droppable - hover class highlighting two block while using mode Tolerance "touch"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I'm having the issue where i try to hightlight the droppable area using Hover class, with tolerance mode as "TOUCH", Its hightlighting two droppable areas.. (like below screen shot)

[image] [image]

How to solve this..  [here my fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/MHe75)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. But probably you want to remove the `margin` on the `#draggable`. -- Please clarify your question with the desired solution.

Comment: i want to highlight the droppable area when draggable object overlap on it, I've used tolerance:"touch" option for "Draggable overlaps the droppable any amount". But issues with is its hightlighting both divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarifiying your question, I still think you have to remove the margin on the `draggable`.

```
#draggable {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; /* remove this line */
}
```

It seems like the `draggable` element including the `margin`, is bigger than the `droppable` element and therefore the `dropped` status is set although the element does not seems to touch the upper `droppable` yet.

[image: highlighted margin and padding]

**Please check the [updated sample](http://jsfiddle.net/MHe75/1/).**